# Material theory of induction: why not abandon induction altogether?

Tags: epistemology, philosophy-of-science, induction

John Norton defends a [material theory of induction](https://www.jstor.org/stable/10.1086/378858?Search=yes&resultItemClick=true&searchText=Material%20theory%20of%20induction&searchUri=%2Faction%2FdoBasicSearch%3FQuery%3DMaterial%2Btheory%2Bof%2Binduction%26acc%3Doff%26wc%3Don%26fc%3Doff%26group%3Dnone&ab_segments=0%2Fbasic_SYC-5187_SYC-5188%2Fcontrol&refreqid=fastly-default%3A86ca57fc0d470ea6990c87cab1438426&seq=1), based on the idea that universal inference schemes cannot account for the strength of inductive inferences. Whether a specific induction is good or bad, he argues, rather depends on relevant *facts*.

Now, there are problems with this view, but what I am concerned about is why Norton would not go down that road and dispense with induction altogether. Consider his favorite example:

> *Some* samples of the element bismuth melt at 271°C. Therefore, *all* samples of the element bismuth melt at 271°C.

In contrast to many/most inferences of the form [some As are B, therefore all As are B], this is supposed to be a good inference because of the fact that:

> elements like bismuth are *generally* uniform in their properties.

Sure, this does not *entail* that all samples of the element bismuth melt at 271°C, so we are still in the business of inductive reasoning. But then again, *how* does it support the above conclusion at all, if not by virtue of some inductive logic? Norton does not seem to make any progress, whereas we could infer by way of deduction that *probably* all samples melt at that point. And yet he insists that this is not what he is getting at.

Any ideas why not? Thanks!

(I must admit not to have read the [draft](https://www.pitt.edu/%7Ejdnorton/papers/material_theory/material_theory_April_23_chapters/material.html) for his book yet.)

Comment: I think his point is that induction proceeds by applying direct domain-specific inference schemas rather than adjoining domain-specific non-logical postulates to the inductive base, and then applying universal inference schemas to the combination, as you suggest. Apparently, this better mirrors the actual practice where such postulates are rarely spelled out, as they are highly context sensitive, and material schemas operate tacitly on skill and expertise. There is also a problem with spelling them out in principle, as that requires delimiting (vague and often unknown) boundaries in advance.

Comment: Thanks! However, it seems that this is not quite Norton's point. In his book he offers the following rejoinder: "Might there still be a residual universal formal schema or inductive rule that contributes to the warrant? Such a schema or rule, however, would in turn be subject to the same analysis just given. [...] That is, the warrant for its use is the factual supposition that world is hospitable to it. [...] That is, the truth of the background factual assumptions, when construed broadly enough, is all that is needed to authorize the inductive inference." (ch. 2, 9)

Comment: I think this just means that there is no point postulating general "uniformity of nature" because uniformity of nature is again needed to apply the postulate. Since "the truth of the background factual assumptions" needs to be operationalized to do something I read it as just a stand-in for domain-specific schemas that operate directly rather than by adjoining "factual truths" with "uniformity of nature".

Comment: Well, if we abandoned induction we'd have to do without most electric motors and generators, power transformers, and the like.  How would you power your computer?

Comment: @ Hot Licks: No kidding?

Comment: To be honest, I find the debate verbal and pedantic. Inductivists say there is a universal schema operative in all instances of induction, "all observed As are Bs, hence all As are Bs", or something like it. Norton says no, induction is valid "in virtue" of "facts alone", and there is just formal similarity across different instances. The disagreement seems to be along the lines of realism/nominalism about the ontological status of "schemas", although neither side spells it out that way. It seems like a distinction without a difference in application, which is the only place induction matters.

Comment: You may find [Achinstein, The War on Induction: Whewell Takes On Newton and Mill (Norton Takes On Everyone)](https://www.jstor.org/stable/10.1086/656540) interesting.

Comment: I am not so sure ... Norton's argument is not just that there is formal similarity across different instances, but that there is formal similarity across 'good' and 'bad' instances, where the material facts make all the difference. This is not exactly news - nobody thinks that induction works in a knowledge vacuum, I guess. It is still worth emphasizing, as too many studies (e.g. on scientific realism) ignore the epistemological consequences.

Comment: Thanks for the tip!